Can not set iTerm2 tab title
I want to configure my iTerm2 so that it shows on the title of each tab (not the window title) my current working directory.
From the iTerm2 docs, I concluded that I can do this under
Preferences -> my profile -> Window
and set a check mark on "Custom Tab Title".
After this, I am supposed to enter an interpolated string for the tab title. According to the docs, an interpolated string has the form \( ...), where I can put a Swift expression between the parenthesis, for instance a variable name.
The predefined variable for my working directory is path. I therefore put \(path) into this field, but the tab title does not change.
The default value for the title seems to contain the profile name and the name of the current shell, which is indentical to what happens to be the Window title.
What did I do wrong?

Found the solution with the help of the iTerm2 developers:
The correct entry in the field Custom Tab Title is:
\(currentSession.path)

This sets the tab title, and leaves the window title unmodified.

From the documentation

Session Title. This is the label that is shown in split pane title bars (if present). By default the session title is also the tab title. You can override this default with Window > Edit Tab Title.

So one way to achieve desired result in tab title is Profile > General > Title and select from dropdown list PWD (it is possible to select more than one, so  Job - PWD, User:PWD etc combinations can be set).

This is not really helpful, for two reason: (1) It also affects the Window title, not only the tab title. (2) I can't enter an interpolated string, so I can't format the text how I like.

Have you tried \(tab.currentSession.path) ?

Where exactly should I enter this?

This is interpolated string for Custom Tab Title

I don't see a difference to before: The tab title still looks like  XXX (-zsh) YYY, where XXX is the name of my profile and YYY is the path to my working directory. If I leave Custom Tab Title empty, I see exactly the same information.
